# clicar em um botao e aparecer a hora dentro de uma div

Tags: html5

Estou criando um sistema de ponto eletrônico simples, e estou tentando colocar a hora dentro de uma determinada div, no momento em que o usuario clicar no link entrar, a hora que ele clicou neste link aparecer dentro de uma div. O codigo do meu botao estar assim: 
Estou usando o Html5 e CSS, de preferencia nessas linguagem, mas pode se em JaVASCRPIT, grato.

```html
<div id="entrada1">Hora da Entrada </div> 
<!-- Preciso que a hora apareça aqui-->
   <div id="botao-entrar"> 
      <div class="botao" > <a href="a definir se vai precisar" class="botao" > Entrar </a> </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ação só pode ser feita com Javascript o código fica assim

```
    <div id="recebeHora">
    Hora da Entrada
    </div><br>
    <button onclick="pegaData()" >Entrar</button>

    <script>
    function pegaData() {
    var data = new Date();

    var hora    = data.getHours();          // 0-23
    var min     = data.getMinutes();        // 0-59
    var seg     = data.getSeconds();        // 0-59
    var mseg    = data.getMilliseconds();   // 0-999
    var tz      = data.getTimezoneOffset(); // em minutos

    // Formata a data e a hora (note o mês + 1)
    var str_hora = hora + ':' + min + ':' + seg;
    document.getElementById("recebeHora").innerHTML = "Hora da Entrada"+str_hora;
    }
```

Comment: Funcionou legal, Duas coisas ficou sobrepondo o nome "hora da entrada" o primeiro lá no começo, preciso dele porque esta editado no css, Como mante-lo, e como mudar a cor dos numeros que aparecem, nao pode ser pela div pq jah estar pronta para o "hora da entrada" como disse antes.

Comment: '<div>
    <divclass="HR" style="display: inline;">
   Hora da Entrada&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="RHR" style="display: inline;" id="recebeHora"></div>
    </div><br> CSS = .HR{
  color: red;
}
.RHR{
  color: blue;
}' substitua o html por esse e estilize as div´s de acordo com o a classe

Answer (score 0):

Veja o código abaixo funcionando:

```js
$("#botao-entrar").click(function(){
   $('#datetime').html(getDataHora());
  return false;
});


function getDataHora() {
  // variáveis
  var data = new Date();
  var hora = data.getHours();
  var minutos = data.getMinutes();
  var segundos = data.getSeconds(); 
  var mes = data.getMonth()+1;
  var dia = data.getDate();
  
  // zero à esquerda se necessário
  dia = dia < 10 ? '0' + dia :  dia;
  mes = mes < 10 ? '0' + mes: mes;
  hora =  hora < 10 ? '0' + hora: hora;
  minutos = minutos < 10 ? '0' + minutos : minutos;
  segundos = segundos  < 10 ? '0' + segundos : segundos;
  
  
  // monta resultado
  var resultado = dia + "/" + mes + "/" + data.getFullYear() + " " + hora + ':' + minutos + ':' + segundos;
  
  
  return resultado;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="entrada1">Hora da Entrada </div> 


<!-- Preciso que a hora apareça aqui-->
<div id="datetime"></div>


<div id="botao-entrar"> 
      <div class="botao"> 
        <a href="a definir se vai precisar" class="botao" >Entrar</a>
      </div>
</div>
```